# Prove taht $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in (\alpha, \beta)$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x\in [a,b], x\not \in (\alpha, \beta)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Can someone explain the circled parts of this proof? We want to prove $f$ is integrable where $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in (\alpha, \beta)$ and $f(x) = 0$ if  $x\in [a,b]$ and $x\not \in (\alpha, \beta)$ 
[image]
[image]

I maybe understand $$\sum_{p+1\leq i \leq q-1} (x_i - x_{i-1}) \leq S \leq \sum_{p\leq i \leq q} (x_i - x_{i-1})$$  after writing down the explicit forms of these two summations, but the underlined sentence still looks confusing to me. I doubt if I can construct a proof like this if I am given questions need to use this technique

Comment: In the first part, he is just dividing the interval, up to the first index in which the partition touches the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$. So, wen you have a partition you can choose a first and a last subindex in which the interval $(x_{p},x_{p+1}))$ is contained in the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$, so he can argue that $x_{i}^{'}$ belongs to $(\alpha,\beta)$.